# How does df.combine() works?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0], 'B': [None, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 0]})
df1.combine(df2, take_smaller, fill_value=-5)
```

The above code yields [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdfFP.png). Where does the 4.0 come from?

Comment: can you provide the code for ```take_smaller```?

Answer (score 6):

From example in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html)

```
take_smaller = lambda s1, s2: s1 if s1.sum() < s2.sum() else s2
```

This says if sum of a series in df1 is less than sum of the series in df2 , return series from df1 else from df2.

So when you do:

```
df1.combine(df2, take_smaller)

   A    B
0  0  3.0
1  0  0.0
```

This works fine.

However when you do a `fill_value=-5` , then the sum of second series in the first dataframe becomes smaller since `fill_value` first fills NaN and then compares. (-5+4) < (3+0) , hence `-5 and 4` is returned.

> fill_value scalar value, default None
> The value to fill NaNs with prior to passing any column to the merge func.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are refering to [doc example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html)

```
take_smaller = lambda s1, s2: s1 if s1.sum() < s2.sum() else s2
```

if so

Here you are using `fill_value=-5` so column `B` passed in function would be
`[-5,4]` and `[3,0]`
so `-5 + 4 = -1` is less than `3 + 0 = 3` hence `[-5, 4]` returned.